# How can I perform row wise 2 way Anova for a proteomic dataset which contains more than 5000 proteins in R?

Tags: r, anova, rowwise

In my dataset I have control and treatment groups for four plant varieties, with four replicates for each variety

Below is the format of the dataset with just two plant varieties (I have ~6000 proteins in my dataset) I need to do 2 way anova to see the differences of the treatment and variety and to get P value for each protein for treatment and variety effect. Can someone please help me to get this Anova done in R?

This link shows how my dataset looks
[proteomic dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7E47.png)

Comment: Can you post data in `dput` format? Given the number of columns, subset the data with something like this: `cols <- seq_len(which(names(df) == "TreatmentVariety2_4")); dput(head(df[cols]))`.

Comment: Sorry. I'm extremely new to R. Is there any other way that I could send the dataset to you to look at and give it a try to get this 2 way Anova done?